# Using JetBrains' Code With Me plugin with either IntelliJ or Android Studio, how can a device be shown to all members?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have successfully started the Code With Me plugin on both IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate) and Android Studio (Electric Eel). Guests can start an Android app running but cannot see the (emulated) device, let alone a physical device controlled by the host.

One way to show an emulated device might be to split the device display window from the IDE and share that window in an IDE panel. I have yet to try this but I wonder if there is a simpler, better, recommended way.

Comment: In live presentations, [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) has been use to show both emulator & physical devices from the desktop. How performant when used over a video conference call/desktop sharing service may depend on your PC.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Nice! I've used AirDroid in the past for this but scrcpy is much better IMHO at first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't currently supported, but we're hoping to implement it in a future version. You can vote for and follow [CWM-6152](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CWM-6152/Support-for-development-of-Mobile-GUIs) and [GTW-2455](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-2455/Remote-development-for-mobile-apps) for updates.